# PHP Looping through entire multidimensional array but only giving one result back

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have got an multidimensional array on which I run a foreach loop.

I basically want to see if I've got the country_url stored in an database. If it is in the database then I'll echo "exists" but if it doesn't then I want to echo "doesn't exist". I don't want it to tell me for each array if it exists or not, but I want the foreach loop to tell me whether the country_url exists in one of the arrays or not.

```
foreach ($countriesForContinent as $country) {
    if ($country['country_url']==$country_url) {
        echo "exists";
    } else {
        echo "doesn't exist";
    }
}
```

Would anyone be able to help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$exist = false;    
foreach ($countriesForContinent as $country) {
        if ($country['country_url']==$country_url) {
            $exist = true;
            break;
        }
    }

if ($exist){
   echo "exists";
} else {
   echo "doesn't exist";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store a variable and then use `break` to terminate the loop once the item is found:

```
$exists = false;
foreach ($countriesForContinent as $country) {
  if ($country['country_url']==$country_url) {
    $exists = true;
    break;
  }
}

if ($exists) {
  echo "Success!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$text = "doesn't exist";

foreach ($countriesForContinent as $country) {
    if ($country['country_url']==$country_url) {
        $text = "exists";
        break;
    }
}

echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers, you could do the following:-

```
echo (in_array($country_url, array_map(function($v) { return $v['country_url']; }, $countriesForContinent))) ? 'exists' : 'does not exist';
```

This is probably slightless less efficient though as it will essentially loop through all `$countriesForContinent` rather than finding a match and `break`[ing].